# error trying to cast variable and pass to a new activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm doing a simple app to make a calculation using user input but I'm having trouble using the Android Math class to do the calculations.The compiler is telling me

> cannot cast from EditText to double

which I need to do in order to use the `atan` and `pow` math functions.

The second thing I'm not sure of is how to display the calculations in my `editTexts` with id's: mark1 and mark2.

My MainActivity looks like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //setting the variables to the xml id's and setting the click listener on the calc button
        offsetLength = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.offLength);
        offsetDepth = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.offDepth);
        ductDepth = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ductDepth);
        calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calc);
        calculate.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);  
    }

    //called when button is clicked.
    public void OnClick(View v)
    {

        //calculations here:
        double tri1,tri2;
        double marking1,marking2;

        marking1 = pow((double)offsetLength,2) + Math.pow((double)offsetDepth,2);
        tri1 = (float)offsetDepth/(float)offsetLength;
        tri2 = (float)ductDepth/Math.atan((float)tri1);
        marking2 = ductDepth/Math.atan(float)(tri2);

        //passing the calc results to my CalcResult activity.
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, CalcResult.class);   
        myIntent.putExtra("number1", marking1);
        myIntent.putExtra("number2", marking2);

        startActivity(myIntent);
        Intent i = new Intent(this,CalcResult.class);
        break;

        }

    }
```

This is the CalcResult class where I "try" to pass the two calculation results to their editTexts:

```
public class CalcResult extends MainActivity
{
    EditText res1,res2;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);
        res1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark1);
        res2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark2);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Double mark1 = bundle.double("marking1");
        Double mark2 = bundle.double("marking2");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this

```
 double marking1,marking2; // double
 marking1 = pow((double)offsetLength,2) + Math.pow((double)offsetDepth,2); 
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, CalcResult.class);   
 myIntent.putExtra("number1", marking1);
```

While retrieving you have this

```
 String mark1 = bundle.getString("marking1"); // retrieving as string
```

Change to

```
 double mark1 = bundle.getDouble("marking1"); // similar for mark2
```

**Update**

You have this

```
 offsetLength = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.offLength);
```

Then

```
 marking1 = pow((double)offsetLength,2) + Math.pow((double)offsetDepth,2);
```

You are not even getting the value from editext.

In on click

```
 String getoffsetlength = offsetLength.getText().toString();
```

Now convert the string to double of float according to your requirement

```
 double off = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetlength);
```

Comment: okay,so it should be like this: `double mark1 = bundle.getDouble("marking1");` but what else am I doing wrong with the calculations?, as I'm getting casting errors there.

Comment: @user2815899 you should get the text from editext and convert it to a format you want

Comment: @user2815899 where do you extract text from editext. you are directly using a editext object that's why you get that exception

Comment: The compiler i telling me I cannot cast from EditText to double which I need to do i norder to use the `atan` and `pow` math functions.

Comment: @user2815899 edittext is an object not a value. you must do your operation on numbers not on edittext object. did you check the update. check the update and then try

Comment: okay,I set my offsetLength to getoffsetlength etc.But when I change it I'm still getting an erorr about casting from string to double.Any idea?

Comment: @user2815899 pls check the whole post `double off = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetlength)` convert string to double. this is basic java stuff. google it or check the docs

Comment: @user2815899 also enclose the same in try catch . catch `NumberFormatException`.  if its not a number entered by user you get that excpetion you can catch and handle properly

Comment: Thank you for the help,I'm a bit rusty on Java syntax.